# What is a real world phenomena that exhibits a projective plane topology?

Tags: general-topology

The earth’s orbit around the sun exhibits a torus topology with the revolution as one axis and rotaion around earths axis as the other. But I cannot think of any examples where the topology is a projective plane. Does anyone have a good real world example?

Comment: What do you mean by "real world phenomena"? The projective plane is nonorientable, so it can't be embedded into 3-d space (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745135/how-to-visualize-the-real-projective-plane-mathbb-rp2-in-three-dimensions-i). On the other hand, if you think of objects doing something in Euclidian space, the objects you tend to think of (like a planet orbiting in space) tend to be implicitly embedded. Probably the projective plane can appear as embedded in spacetime as a 4d manifold, but that won't be visualisable anyway.

Comment: What I mean by real world phenomena is some phenomena that is easily relatable to layman that exhibits a configuration space that is a projective plane. It doesn’t have to be physical objects embedded in 3D space. The earth’s rotation around the sun is not actually a  torus but its configuration space has a torus topology.

Comment: Would you count the set of straight lines through a given point in space as a “real world phenomenon”? That's often taken as the *definition* of the projective plane.

Comment: That is exactly what I wasnt looking for. Haha Abstract and geometric examples are common but remain elusive to the layman…

Comment: You need to define *layman*

Comment: I really don't get it when people want someone to precisely define something that is not mathematical or purely logic. You kill CREATIVITY, because CREATIVITY does not have a precise mathematical definition!!!

Comment: What I mean by layman is normal people who are not math or physics majors.

Answer (score 3):

A version of this question came up awhile ago on MathOverflow and there was a [great answer given there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45838/290): the configuration space of a [nematic liquid crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_crystal#Nematic_phase) is $\mathbb{RP}^2$, because a nematic liquid crystal is basically a rod. This is relevant to classifying what are called [topological defects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_defect) of materials made out of nematic liquid crystals. You can check out the link for more details and some nice pictures.