# Definition of projective n-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014-c6.pdf and he defines **projective n-space** to be the set of 1-dimensional subspaces of $K^{n+1}$. I initially thought that it might be easier to remember if defining the projective n-space to be 1-dimensional subspaces of $K^n$. What are some good reasons to define it to be 1-dimensional subspaces of $K^{n+1}$? Is it because in this case, projective 1-space actually makes sense (not trivial)?

Also, is it that when we talk about projective n-space, n is usually a positive number (not including $0$)?

Thank you!

Comment: It’s because you want the projective $n$-space to be $n$ dimensional.

Comment: Yes, it is for dimension reasons.

Comment: A circle is one dimensional but we normally draw it in two dimensions. It's the same idea with projective spaces.

Comment: Maybe could be useful take a look of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85394/why-the-emphasis-on-projective-space-in-algebraic-geometry

Comment: Thank you! @DankaMakabre Another question, do we consider projective $0$-space? Is it that we don't consider it because it's too trivial (i.e. $n$ in projective $n$-space is always a positive integer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It’s because you want the projective $n$-space to be $n$
> dimensional. – [Danka Makabre](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1122499/danka-makabre)